# How to optimize a code in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is very simple, can I optimize Code B in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
val pendingIntent = if (isServer)
        PendingIntent.getService(myContext, 0, myIntent, 0)
    else
        PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0, myIntent, 0)
```

**Code B**

```
var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder? =null

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("ID", "My", importance)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, notificationChannel.id)
} else {
    builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext)
}
```

Comment: You can do the same as in code A, remove type hint and use the if statemant as an expression. Nevertheless, the question type "How to improve my code" is off-topic and should be posted at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code A is fine the way it is.

Code B can be simplified by making your `builder` a non-nullable val instead of a nullable var, by making it the result of an `if` expression (like you do in Code A). The type of `builder` can also be inferred here, you can optionally leave it off. Additionally, inside the first if block, you can make it a bit cleaner by using the `importance` value directly, instead of declaring it as value (which you use in one place only).

```
val builder = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("ID", "My", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, notificationChannel.id)
} else {
    NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext)
}
```

Anything more than that (using `also` or `apply` in the if block) I would argue makes it less clear in this case. I'm not super fond of the call to `notificationManager` in the middle there, but I'm not an Android dev and am not sure if that side effect is idiomatic or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("ID", "My", importance)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
                NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, notificationChannel.id)
            } else {
                NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext)

            }
```

Comment: you should add some explanation and not only a code solution.

Comment: @pixix4 yeah i know but knida run short of time :P sorry